# limit of functions where $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus

What is the  limit of ${(\cot x)}^{\sin x}$ as $x \to \infty$? I think we can't use L' Hospital law here. So how to get answer?

Comment: $\cot x$ and $\sin x$ have no limit. So chances are high that the power hasn't either.

Comment: Are you sure this converges?

Comment: @Strants: hem, read my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh.  I guess I should read more than just the comments. . .  I've deleted my comment, since you already addressed it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function is periodic and non constant, thus it can't have a limit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not well-defined because $\cot x$ is undefined at $z\pi$, $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Even if you ignore this fact, the function equals $0$ at every $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$ and equals $1$ at every $y_n=\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi$, so no chance for the limit to exist.